# How to prove that a simple graph having 11 or more vertices or its complement is not planar?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

It is an exercise on a book again. If a simple graph $G$ has 11 or more vertices,then either G or its complement  $\overline { G } $ is not planar.

How to begin with this? Induction?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe using Kuratowki's theorem.

Comment: Or maybe Euler's formula. What is the maximum number of edges that a simple planar graph with 11 vertices can have?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It follows from the Euler's formula that a simple planar graph $G$ with $m$ edges and $n\geq 3$ vertices must satisfy (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph))
$$\tag{1}m\leq 3n-6.$$
For a graph $G$ with $m$ edges and $n$ vertices, its complement $\overline{G}$ has $\displaystyle\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-m$ edges. Therefore, if $\overline{G}$ is also planar, by $(1)$ we have
$$\tag{2}\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-m\leq 3n-6.$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$, we obtain
$$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\leq 6n-12,$$
which implies that $n\leq 10$.

Comment: Oh,the book I am reading now doesn't have this formula m≤3n−6 ... Now it seems not to be a good book.

Comment: I've had this doubt, could it be that both $G \text{ and }  \overline G$ are not planar?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Of course.  What this proved was that *at least one of* $G$ and $\overline{G}$ must be nonplanar.  If you want specific constructions of graphs who are nonplanar whose complements are also nonplanar, see for example [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280034/draw-a-non-planar-graph-whose-complement-is-a-non-planar-graph).