# Planar graph proof

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prove that a simple graph having 11 or more vertices or its complement is not planar?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128657/how-to-prove-that-a-simple-graph-having-11-or-more-vertices-or-its-complement-is)

I need to prove some graph problem.

Let G be planar graph with more than 10 vertices. I need to prove the its complement graph G' is not planar.

Comment: see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128657/how-to-prove-that-a-simple-graph-having-11-or-more-vertices-or-its-complement-is/128665#128665

Comment: Thanks, It's exacly the same :D

Answer (score 3):

If n ≥ 3 then e ≤ 3n − 6; and If n ≥ 3 and there are no cycles of length 3, then e ≤ 2n − 4.
you can use this too to prove by contradiction....

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try to show that $G'$ contains a full subgraph of 5 vertices $K_5$ or the full bipartite graph $K_{3,3}$.